# Athena query displays data differently than in S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Athena Query is changing few of data points to 0.

During data sanity I found that a particular column was showing huge difference on dashboard and in S3 files, data displayed on dashboard was around 40k and on reading it after downloading file from S3 was around 80k.

Since I am querying data directly from S3 using Athena, the datasource remains the same for aAhena and file download. I am wondering why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

Eg:
Athena Query Results :
[image: Results through Athena Query]

Data in S3:
[image: Data Stored in S3]

Queried the data through a simple select query:

```
SELECT "orderid","orderdate","total tax"
FROM gbc_owss"
```

The datatype in Athena for the `total tax` column was `double`.

EDIT: Solved the above issue, it was indeed a delimiter issue and that was pushing the values to next column thus making it look like athena is changing values but that wasn't the case.

Comment: Can we see the whole row please? Do you have an example of the file so we can reproduce? Is that the `orderId` or the `totalTax`?

Comment: Please edit your Question to show us the rows in the input file that produced these outputs. Also please show us the DDL for the table.

Comment: What is the visualization tool you use? 
You need to check the definition of the table schema (in Glue and Athena). It might have issues with the file format (delimiters, empty columns...) that cause Athena to read the data differently than intended.

Comment: @Guy You are absolutely correct! It was the delimiter that was pushing the values to next column btw I was using aws grafana for visualization.